# Remove <br />{EMPTY_SPACE}

Tags: php

I have this preg_replace function:

```
$comment = nl2br($comment);
$comment = preg_replace( '/(<br(?: \\/)?>\\r?\\n?\\r?)(?=\\1)/is', '', $comment);
```

It works fine, but lets say I do a whitespace and then hit enter and keep doing so, it then can repeat `<br />`.

How do I also remove `<br />{SPACE}`?

or, How do I limit only one `<br />` at each enter and remove `<br />{whitespace}` at the same time?

Example:

```
test
ENTER + SPACE
ENTER + SPACE
ENTER + SPACE
test2

Output:

test
test2
```

Comment: what if they enter `<br/>` with NO space in side it? You should not be using regexes to clean up html.

Comment: This is cleaning up a nl2br function, forgot to mention that.